# Python Socket Programming ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

This is my code for the server program:

```
import socket
soket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8011

soket.bind((HOST,PORT))
print("%s:%d server başlatıldı." % (HOST,PORT))
print("Kullanıcı bekleniyor.")
soket.listen(2)

baglanti,adres = soket.accept()
print("Bir bağlantı kabul edildi.", adres)

baglanti.send("Hoşgeldiniz efendim , hoşgeldiniz.")

data = baglanti.recv(1024)
print(data)

soket.close()
```

And this is for the client:

```
import socket
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(("localhost", 8011))
clientsocket.send('hello')
```

Although I first start the server program and then the client program, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Esat/Desktop/Python/Softwares/socketto copy.py", line 3,  in <module>
    clientsocket.connect(("localhost", 8011))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: I know some words are written in Turkish but they don't have any significance to the program.

Comment: Silly question, but are you _sure_ that the server is running ? Also the server should first `recv` and then `send` .

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `localhost`, it is better to use LAN (local) IP. You can get your local IP by running ipconfig (in Windows) or `ifconfig` (in GNU/Linux or Mac OS). Your local IP should be something like `192.168.1.x`.